# Rails: Update a Global Variable to Update a Table Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I heard you could do this with ajax, but I have never used ajax therfore I know nothing about it.

I am looking for a way to update a variable say when you click a `button`.

I have an embedded ruby `.each function` in html that created columns to add to an html table. I need to use ajax to get the latest array of all the `sell_requests` updating the value `@sell_requests=Sell_request.all`. How would I proceed to doing this?

Also, do I need the file to be a coffescript file for ajax to work?

Thank you. Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: You should go through this guide [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: Do I need to be using coffeescript to use ajax?

Comment: No you don't need to use CoffeeScript, JavaScript will do.